# Can I yank the names of all marked files from a dired buffer?

Tags: dired

I'm working on several files in sequence and want to build a buffer of file names to log my progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the first time I've seen Emacs use "copy" internally, rather than "yank".

`dired-copy-filename-as-kill`

Comment: It does not use copy instead of yank. It copies text to the `kill-ring`, as if you had killed it - the same thing it does for `M-w` and `copy-region-as-kill`.

Comment: Upvoted for the command (but Drew is right -- copying and yanking are different, and `copy-*-as-kill` is a naming scheme used by a number of commands), but also noting that it's unfortunately not as useful as it should be for multiple marked files, as it leaves them on a single line, unquoted, and space-separated, meaning that you can't actually tell what the filenames are unless you know for certain that none of them contain spaces. You can easily fix that with a modified copy of the function, but this is probably worth raising a bug report/feature request about.

Comment: Emacs always uses `yank` in "pasting" reference.. imagine *yanking* text off the kill-ring and putting it into the buffer.