# Copy all file names that match regexp

Tags: dired, copy-paste

In a `dired` buffer of a directory, how do I copy the file names of all files matching `[tT]ypolog[yi]`?

Getting them from an `elisp` list format, `\n` separated format or otherwise into a `python` list format will be trivial, so the precise content of the kill ring matters little.

Answer (score 11):

Use function `directory-files`, for which `C-h f` tells you:

```
directory-files is a built-in function in `C source code'.

(directory-files DIRECTORY &optional FULL MATCH NOSORT)

Return a list of names of files in DIRECTORY.
There are three optional arguments:
If FULL is non-nil, return absolute file names.  Otherwise return names
 that are relative to the specified directory.
If MATCH is non-nil, mention only file names that match the regexp MATCH.
If NOSORT is non-nil, the list is not sorted--its order is unpredictable.
 Otherwise, the list returned is sorted with `string-lessp'.
 NOSORT is useful if you plan to sort the result yourself.
```

In this case, you provide your regexp as argument `MATCH`:

`M-: (directory-files default-directory nil "[tT]ypolog[yi]")`

And you need not be in a Dired buffer to use this.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `counsel-find-file` from the `counsel` MELPA package, you can press <kbd>M-w</kbd> to copy all current matches. It works with regex patterns as input. Then press <kbd>C-g</kbd> if you don't wont to select a file afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

You can mark all files whose names match a regular expression using `dired-mark-files-regexp`, and then copy them to the kill ring them (see [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/21231/2702)) using `dired-copy-filename-as-kill`.

Unfortunately, this does not result in a list that is in any way nicely separated, because the file names are just concatenated using by  , so if your file names may contain spaces, you get a mess.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a shell command to list the directory (ls -1), then use keep-lines to delete the lines that do not match your regex. the buffer then contains just the  file names that you want, one per line.

Comment: That is actually (similar to, because using viper it started with something like `:!ls`) what I did the first time, but I felt like it was more cumbersome than it should be.